# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null. Context _generated_background_page.html

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing a chrome extension and am trying to bind an event listener to an HTML button via an external JS file.

The event listener works, however Chrome throws the following error:[image]

This is manifest.json, background.js, and popup.html file in that order:

{
    "name": "DRIP",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "DRIP is an automation tool for purchasing limted items",
    "permissions": ["storage", "tabs"],

```
"browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
},

"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
}
```

}

```
    function myAlert(){
  alert('hello world')
}

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      document.getElementById('alertButton').addEventListener('click', myAlert);
  });
```

__

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>

</head>
<body>
    <form name='testForm'>
        <input type='button' id='alertButton' value='click me'>
    </form>
    <script language='javascript' src='background.js' defer></script>
</body>
```

I'm sorry if my formatting isn't great. Input is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried to put the script into the `head` tag ?

Comment: @Ayfri yes, I tried that and the same error still occurs.

Comment: @Sam, Do you want the alert to open on page load? It is working here https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/QWjNaNQ

Comment: @ManirajMurugan I want the alert to open on the button click. My extension does that successfully but I get the error described above and want to get rid of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
}
```

That's for running tasks in the background and loads a background page.  It is running on a blank page `_generated_background_page.html` (that it generated for you).  Note that you can set the background page's html if you needed to.
Popup is a separate background page with the html set to the `default_popup` value.  That is the page you get when you click the icon and get a popup.

Official docs for reference: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages